# String input xor encryption program

Tags: c++, encryption, xor

Description:
I am trying to write a basic program for fun that will input a string/phrase then xor encrypt it and in the end cout the encrypted phrase. I am working on a mac so I will be compiling with xcode and running it in terminal.

Problem:
I am having an error with inputting a string that can be xor encrypted, see code below:

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string mystr;
cout << "What's the phrase to be Encrypted? ";
//getline (cin, mystr);

char string[11]= getline (cin, mystr); //ERROR: Array must be initialized with brace-enclosed initializer
cout << "Phrase to be Encrypted: " << mystr << ".\n";
char key[11]="ABCDEFGHIJ";  //The Encryption Key, for now its generic
for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
{
    string[x]=mystr[11]^key[x];
    cout<<string[x];
}
return 0;
}
```

Help:
please identify and explain or provide examples why I am receiving the error code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `getline` correctly. You're also trying to use `string` as a variable when it's already defined as a type. I'd try something more like this:

```
getline(cin, mystr);

string result;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    result.push_back(mystr[i] ^ key[i]);
    cout << result[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of getline is a stream and you can't assign that to a char array. To initialize an array you have to use:

```
char s[10] = {'h', 'i', 0};
```

Or the shorthand for this in case of a char array:

```
char s[10] = "hi";
```

In your problem, you'd probably want to use the commented out getline statement and

```
const char* string = mystr.c_str();
```