# Why can I only xor decrypt the first two characters of my input stream?

Tags: c++, string, encryption, xor

Description:
I am writing/exploring xor encryption/decryption in c++ code for fun. I have asked previous questions on these two topics:[Very long string input to xor encryption program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588392/very-long-string-input-to-xor-encryption-program?noredirect=1#comment36204215_23588392) and [String input xor encryption program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588202/string-input-xor-encryption-program/23588320?noredirect=1#23588320).

I have developed the code below that will prompt the user for a string and it is supposed to xor the string with the key in the code. The way this encryption works is that I should be able to input a string and get a encrypted string. If I run the same encrypted string through the same function I should get the original string back. See working code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
while (1)
{
string mystr;
cout << "What's the phrase to be Encrypted? ";

char key[11]="ABCDEFGHIJ";  //The Encryption Key, for now its generic
getline(cin, mystr);

string result;

for (int i=0; i<mystr.size(); i++) {
    result.push_back(mystr[i] ^ key[i%11]);
    cout << result[i];
}
cout << "\n";


}
return 0;
}
```

Question:
I am only able to put a string of length 2 characters into the program and be able to have an encrypted string returned back of length 2. If I put anymore characters into the program I will only get the first 2 original characters back. Why is this?

Please respond with clear explanations and or examples. Thanks

Comment: `char key[11]="ABCDEFGHIJK"; ` should throw an error! The array can only hold 10 characters and a null character at end.

Comment: What was the third character in your input string?

Comment: your right its two long, the reason is is because I had something different in there that was 11 but I dont want to share my passwords out on the internet so I changed it.

Comment: Lets say I enter rx the encrypt is S/ then I put that back into the function and get rx however entering rxv still gives me S/.

Comment: XOR on readable characters can result in zero bytes if one of the input characters happens to be the same as one in the key. I would use a std::vector<char> here and then print it out in hex form so even the zero bytes are visible. Another issue is, you may end up with low ascii characters like backspace, cr, lf, tab, etc that may (or may not) mess up a terminal output - a backspace may cause overwriting of previous char while displaying. Otherwise your code seems to be ok, except the size of key[] array. Why not make it char key[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ"; and let the compiler take care of the size.

Comment: Your key contains 10 characters (ignoring the trailing null) so you should use `i%10` to produce indexes 0..9 in the expression `key[i%10]`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to user –  DNT for suggesting this I remove the 11 from:
    char key[11] = "ABCDEFGHIJ"  and let the compiler figure it out.
that suggestion corrected the problem. Final code is below for anyone who may need it since this just a exploratory/fun project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
while (1)
{
string mystr;
cout << "What's the phrase to be Encrypted? ";

char key[]="ABCDEFGHIJ";  //The Encryption Key, for now its generic
getline(cin, mystr);

string result;

for (int i=0; i<mystr.size(); i++) {
    result.push_back(mystr[i] ^ key[i%11]);
    cout << result[i];
}
cout << "\n";


}
return 0;
}
```